# Homeomorphism Question

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Is there any homeomorhpism from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ that transforms an ellipsoid of the form $\{x|x^T A x\leq 1\}$ (=ellipsoid centered at the origin) into a hyperrectangle, and transforms the unit cube $[0,1]^n$ into some convex set?

Comment: Yes, there is...

Comment: Could you please write the homeomorphism, and the image of the ellipsoid and the cube under the homeomorphism, explicitly?

Comment: Wait, do you mean that both objects live in the same $\mathbb{R}^n$ and you want a homeomorphism of this ambient space to itself that has the prescribed effect on the two given subsets? Or do you really want two homeomorphisms: one from elipsoid to hyperrectangle and another one from cube to something convex?

Comment: I want the same homeomorphism for both. Is this possible?

Comment: Ok, but then you need to edit your question in order to make this more clear. Specify what are the domain and the co-domain of the homeomorphism, is it indeed $\mathbb{R}^n$? Also: is there one specific elipsoid that you want to turn into a hyperractangle while keeping ALL possible cubes centered at the origin in the domain of your homeomorphism convex or just one specific cube?

Comment: Yes! Great edit. I will think a bit about the answer.

Comment: Start with the problem in 1 dimensional. Then use that solution ``radially''.

Comment: @Vincent, did you think about the question? :)

Comment: @BenMcKay I don't understand your solution: wouldn't the most obvious solution in 1 dimension be the identity map?

Comment: @DudiFrid Yes, but I'm even more confused now. I can see a map that turns the elipsoid in a hyper-octahedron, I think, but that is not what you want. What complicates matters is that in 2D the two problems are equal. I really hope someone else comes swoopoing in with an elegant solution!